# jquery expander custom class

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery expander here http://plugins.learningjquery.com/expander but couldnt find how to add a custom class to the show more/less links.

There are some I would like blue and others I would like black. I tried adding the summaryClass definition but that didnt do anything.

Does anyone have any ideas how to add a custom class to individual links?

I have tried a couple of other expander plugins but this seems the best one I could find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with CSS.

The Expander plugin places a link wrapped in a span with class **read-more** / **read-less**. So, some CSS to target that link...

```
<style type="text/css">
  #one .read-more a, #one .read-less a { color: black; }
  #two .read-more a, #two .read-less a { color: red; }
</style>
<div id="one" class="expandable">
   This expandable div will have a black [...]
</div>
<div id="two" class="expandable">
   This expandable div will have a red [...]
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There are actually two links added by the plugin:

- One with class .read-less
- One with class .read-more

What you can do is add a specific css class in the container and play with css selectors to customize the look-n-feel of thoses links:

```
<ul>
   <li class="myclass">
       Text
       <span class="read-more"></span>
       <span class="details">
           <span class="read-less"></span>
       </span>
   </li>
</ul>
```

And the css:

```
   .myclass .read-more { /* my styles... */ }
   .myclass .read-less{ /* my styles... */ }
```